# How to get billing cost of GCP project using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to get billing cost of GCP project, but I could not see expected result for the client library that I am using in my code.

I want to get report or spend cost for current month, but it just providing me:

> project_id: "my-project"
> billing_account_name: "billingAccounts/XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
> billing_enabled: true

I am using `billing_v1.GetProjectBillingInfoRequest()` class to get result.

```
from google.cloud import billing_v1
from google.oauth2 import service_account

info = {
    "client_email": "gcserviceacc@XYZ-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
}
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(info)

# Create a client
client = billing_v1.CloudBillingClient(credentials=credentials)
def sample_get_project_billing_info():
    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = billing_v1.GetProjectBillingInfoRequest(
        name="projects/my-project"
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.get_project_billing_info(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
sample_get_project_billing_info()

output:
project_id: "my-project"
billing_account_name: "billingAccounts/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
billing_enabled: true
```

Comment: Sadly, you can't have this information. I have been asking actively for 4 years now to the eng team... Something is promised by the end of the year.... Stay tuned

Comment: There is no API to get billing cost only pricing per SKU. You must export billing data to BigQuery. Then you can query BigQuery using Python + SQL or any language to get cost details. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Comment: You just edited your post to mask information. Edit revisions are readable by everyone with enough points. the `private_key_id` is public information. The service account email is also harmless. Disclosure is not a security risk. You did show the private key but I cannot easily tell if that is the entire private key without decoding it. If yes, immediately delete that key in the Google Cloud Console GUI. Delete the key only, deleting the service account is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As John has pointed, there is only one option if you want to get the costs programatically. It is through the billing exports (Standard usage cost exports, Detailed cost exports). You can set it up by following GCP's documentation https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery.

Once the data starts exporting, you can run queries with filters such as `project-id="xyz"` or `service-name="Dataflow"`.

If you have multiple projects under an Organization, but with the same billing account, you can run complex queries to identify the cost of each project, or each service, or even cost of a single SKU.

You can integrate this billing export table with a third-party service like [Economize](https://www.economize.cloud/) to visualize your entire organization's cost broken down by dimensions like projects, services, SKUs.

[image: GCP cost per project]